# How to catch all value on a single click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<tr>
    <td>x</td>
    <td>y</td>
    <td>z</td>
    <td> href </td>
</tr>
```

On clicking the `href` in `last <td>` I want to catch the value to show these values in the `pop up`. How can I catch these values?

Comment: by "catching" all the values, you mean `x`, `y`, and `z`?

Comment: Please tag your questions better, this got nothing to do with AJAX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
functionn showValues()
{
    var response;
    response = document.getElementById("x").innerHTML;
    response += document.getElementById("y").innerHTML;
    response += document.getElementById("z").innerHTML;

    window.alert(response);
}
</script>
<tr>
    <td id="x">x</td>
    <td id="y">y</td>
    <td id="z">z</td>
    <td onclick="showValues()"> href </td>
</tr>
```

- Create a function that will run onclick. onclick is the handler for click events in javascript.
- Grab the innerHTML of the elements you want.
- Alert the user.

Answer (score 0):

```
            <tr>
          <td><span id="v1">x</span></td>
          <td>y</td>
         <td>z</td>
          <td> href </td>
          </tr>
```

specify span and give id to it and extract the value using document.getElementByID().innerHTML; same for all other rows in javascript

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<script>
function test()
{
var arrCells = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
for (idx=0;idx<arrCells.length-1;idx++) {
  strValue = arrCells[idx].innerHTML;
  alert(strValue);
}
}
</script>
<table>
<tr>
    <td>x</td>
    <td>y</td>
    <td>z</td>
    <td><a href="#" onclick="return test()">href </a></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use siblings() to do it.

```
$("tr td:last").click(function(){
   alert($(this).siblings().text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <tr>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>y</td>
        <td>z</td>
        <td> <a href="#" onclick="catchAll(this)" >clickhere </a><</td>
    </tr>

function catchAll(obj)
{
  var tdNodes=  obj.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes;
}
```

You can using for loop to trace tdNodes .

Answer (score 0):

```
$("td:last").click(function(){
val_of_all_td=[];

$("td").each(function(){
val_of_all_td.push($('this').html());
});
});
```

Array `val_of_all_td` contains all the value of td.

Answer (score 0):

Download jquery and insert it in your script
[jquery](http://jquery.com/)

You can catch your values just one click with DOM Traversal method (contains):

```
$('td:contains(href)').click( function(){
   str= " ";

   $('td').each( function(){
      str+= $(this).text();
   });
   alert(str); // u can change it with your script to display it on pop up
});
```